# What (if anything) does the prefix 'op-' mean in 'operīre'?

Tags: etymology, affixes

<sub>[This question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/234/37) inspired the following: I should verify whether the prefix really means something. I quoted the French version of Wiktionary because the [English version](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aperio#la) does not state the Latin etymons (only the PIE etymons).</sub>

> [operīre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/operio#Latin)
>   De l’indo-européen commun **u̯er-* [1] (« couvrir » → voir [*veru*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/veru#la)) avec le préfixe [*op-*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ob-#la),
>   plutôt qu'un dérivé [2] de [*pario*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pario#la).
>   Voyez son antonyme [*aperio*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aperio#la).

Comment: Please don't ask multiple nearly-identical questions. Also, stems can include things that look like prefixes. That's good Latin.

Comment: Actually, *operīre* and *perīre* aren't related, at least not in the way this question assumes. The former is a fourth-conjugation verb (*operiō*) and the latter is an irregular verb in the same pattern as *īre* (*pereō*).

Comment: It seems that _aperio_ is the anthonym by means of _a+operio_, where either the _o_ was elided in the process, or was undergoing aphaeresis at the time _aperio_ formed. The corresponding [Proto-IE root](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=\data\ie\piet&first=1&off=&text_lat=operio&method_lat=substring&ic_lat=on&sort=proto&ic_any=on) lists an initial vowel as optional. If that is true, there would be no prefixes.

Comment: @Rafael Thanks. Please feel free to edit my question if the quote is wrong.

Comment: The quote seems right. It is just that when there is disagreement between _wiktionary_ and a primary source, I think the primary is preferable

Answer (score 1):

The prefix op- originated ob- (e.g. *obsto* from *opsto), and is visible in *operio* (< *op-u̯eri̯ō) and *oportet*.

The verb derives from PIE *su̯er-, which means  "to close, cover" or "to guard, save".

Given that *aperio* (< *ap-u̯eri̯ō), which means "to open", is formed with the prefix ap-, "**from, out**" (ancient Greek ἀπό), and at the opposite op- means **at, by, around, round about, all around** (ancient Greek ἐπί), in the case of *operio* the prefix could denote that the object is completely closed or enclosed.

For further references see the digital edition of the [Indo-European Etymological Dictionary](http://dnghu.org/indoeuropean.html) of Pokorny-Lubotsky (use the "find" function of the browser and search "aperi" or "operi").