# Is the prefix 'in-' redundant in 'instruere'?

Tags: classical-latin, affixes

<sub>[This](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/234/37) inspired this question; I should verify whether the prefix really means something.</sub>

> [instruere](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=instruct&allowed_in_frame=0)
>   "arrange, prepare, set in order; inform, teach," literally "to build, erect,"
>   from [*in-*²](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=in-&allowed_in_frame=0) "on" + *struere* "to pile, build" (see [structure](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=structure&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.))

*in-* appears superfluous to me, because piling or building something must occur **on** something.

Answer (score 3):

The definition you cite for *instruere* is sparse and leaves most of the uses of the word uncovered. The definition from Lewis & Short is

> 1. to build in or into
> 2. to build, erect, construct
> 3. To set in order, draw up in battle array
> 4. To prepare, make ready, furnish, provide, to equip, fit out
> 5. to procure, provide for, prepare for, furnish
> 6. to provide with information, to teach, instruct

It can also mean "instruct, teach," and "institute" (as in institute a festival), as well as being used in expressions like "lay an ambush" (*insidias instruere*).

So going *strictly* from the definition it might seem redundant, but the way the word is used in practice it actually means something very different from *struere*.