# Is the prefix 'de-' redundant in 'delimitare'?

Tags: etymology, affixes

<sub>[This](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/234/37) inspired this question; I should verify whether the prefix really means something.</sub>

> [delimitare](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=delimit&searchmode=none)
>   "to mark out as a boundary,"
>   from [*de-*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=de-&allowed_in_frame=0) + *limitare*, from *limitem, limes* "boundary, limit" (see [limit](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=limit&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.))

*de-* feels redundant, because it does not appear to distinguish 'delimitare' from  [limitare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/limito#Latin) and because to limit something presumes to "mark out as a boundary" something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lewis Elementary gives the definition of *limito* as

> 1. to enclose within boundaries or limits, to bound
> 2. to fix, settle, determine

and the definition of *delimito* as

> 1. to mark out

I would suggest, given these definitions, that *limito* has the sense of establishing the existence and placement of a boundary ("You stay on your side of the back seat of the car and I'll stay on mine, and neither one of us will cross into the other's territory"), whereas *delimito* has the sense of creating a physical representation of that boundary ("Here, I'll put a piece of tape right down the middle of the seat so we can be sure not to cross the boundary").

I would say therefore that no, *de* in *delimito* is not actually redundant.